# How to enable Grails 2 logging for development

Tags: grails, logging

What's the simplest way to show Grails app log for a developer who is new to Grails?

It could help learning Grails magics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy 2.x : open `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`, and replace contents of log4j block with:

```
log4j = {
  root {
    debug()
  }
}
```

This will enable and send all log to standard out.

Further refining requires studying [grails logging](https://www.google.ee/#q=grails+logging) in more detail.